# How to determine sync is complete offline firebase

Tags: android, firebase, offlineapps

I am using the android sdk with firebase.

How do I know when the offline sync is complete?

```
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    mFirebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    mFirebase.keepSynced(true);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API to know whether there are any outstanding changes that you still have to receive.

I guess it is fair to assume that if you haven't gotten any events from the Firebase server in a few seconds, you probably have all the data that you're listening or synchronizing. Whenever somebody makes a change after that, Firebase sends the actual changes down to your app.